# How to get the sum of values from inside a for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am stuck on a program that gathers input from a user about the buying and selling price of stock and how many shares they have. I am using a for loop to test conditions based on how many options they wish to process. The value of profit is saved after each loop, but as the loop exits only the final value is outputted. Is there a way to keep a total of values assigned to a specific single variable inside a loop and add them and print them out.

here is my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
double buy = 0;
double sell = 0;
double shares = 0;
int options = 0;
double profit = 0;
double totalProfit = 0;
double *pBuy = &buy;
double *pSell = &sell;
double *pShares = &shares;
double *pProfit = &profit;
double *ptotalProfit = &totalProfit;

cout << "Please enter the number of stock option to process:" << endl;
cin >> options;

for ( int i = 0; i < options; i++)
{
cout << "Please enter the buy price for stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
cout << "$"; cin >> *pBuy;
cout << "Please enter the sell price for stock #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
cout << "$"; cin >> *pSell;
cout << "Please enter the shares for the stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
cin >> *pShares;
*pProfit = (*pSell - *pBuy) * *pShares;
}

*pProfit = (*pSell - *pBuy) * *pShares;
cout << "Total Profit is:" << "$" << *pProfit << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the following. Just keep on adding to the `profit` variable. Since, you are not passing this variable to another function by pointer or reference, pointer use is not required.

```
profit = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < options; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter the buy price for stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
    cout << "$"; cin >> buy;
    cout << "Please enter the sell price for stock #" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
    cout << "$"; cin >> bell;
    cout << "Please enter the shares for the stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
    cin >> shares;
    profit += (sell - buy) * shares;
}

cout << "Total Profit is:" << "$" << profit << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have to use the pointers. It is unnecessary. Second you can sum the profit by using the totalProfit variable. Here's the code:

```
    int main()
    {
         double buy = 0;
         double sell = 0;
         double shares = 0;
         int options = 0;
         double profit = 0;
         double totalProfit = 0;
         cout << "Please enter the number of stock option to process:" << endl;
         cin >> options;

         for ( int i = 0; i < options; i++)
         {
               cout << "Please enter the buy price for stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
               cout << "$"; cin >>buy;
               cout << "Please enter the sell price for stock #" << i + 1 << ":" <<endl;
               cout << "$"; cin >> sell;
               cout << "Please enter the shares for the stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
               cin >> shares;
               profit = (sell - buy) * shares;
               totalProfit+=profit;
          }

         cout << "Total Profit is:" << "$" << totalProfit << endl;
    }
```

If you want daily profit stored. You can store them in array.

```
    int main()
    {
         double buy = 0;
         double sell = 0;
         double shares = 0;
         int options = 0;
         double profit = 0;
         double totalProfit = 0;
         cout << "Please enter the number of stock option to process:" << endl;
         cin >> options;
         double profitArray[options];
         for ( int i = 0; i < options; i++)
         {
               cout << "Please enter the buy price for stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
               cout << "$"; cin >>buy;
               cout << "Please enter the sell price for stock #" << i + 1 << ":" <<endl;
               cout << "$"; cin >> sell;
               cout << "Please enter the shares for the stock #" << i + 1 <<":" << endl;
               cin >> shares;
               profit = (sell - buy) * shares;
               profitArray[i]=profit;
               totalProfit+=profit;
          }

         cout << "Total Profit is:" << "$" << totalProfit << endl;
    }
```